# A little lost with calling amadeus API with ruby. Do I need to decode the result?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, amadeus

I'm a beginner at coding and trying to use this with Ruby. I'm trying to get human readable outcome from this code:

```rb
response = amadeus.reference_data.locations.points_of_interest.by_square.get(north: 41.397158, west: 2.160873, south: 41.394582, east: 2.177181)
  
  p response.body #=> The raw response, as a string
  p response.result #=> The body parsed as JSON, if the result was parsable
  p response.data #=> The list of locations, extracted from the JSON
```

and what I get is this as the screenshot [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnTq6.png). Do I need to decode this result ?

Comment: At a glance, looks like valid JSON. What do you think is the problem with it, again?

Comment: Hi, I'm not familiar with JSON. What should I do to convert the result into something that easily readable. Do I need to convert it into ruby format ?

Comment: first you need to define "easily readable".

Comment: I think I understand now... I need to export the JSON data from ruby file into json file. From there I can read them properly and organised including with indentations. and If I want to extract parts of the data, I'll just call them back directly from ruby... can someone confirm if I'm doing the right thing ?

Comment: you don' t need to save this content in a file to get pretty format. try this: `puts JSON.pretty_generate(response.result)`

Comment: thanks, that's what I've been looking for!